# Minecraft LOTR mod Shrek hut easter egg

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I know this seems odd but there is an Easter egg in the LOTR mod for minecraft. I entered the coordinates in the teleport command and nothing was there. Does anyone know the exact coords.

NOTE: this may have been removed I do not know But you may also tell me it has been removed. I heard about it a wiki page on the official wiki did say it was a test for structures staying in the same position

Comment: The easter egg's time was ogre.

Comment: XD ok  i get it now

Comment: LOTR Minecraft Mod Wiki said that it was moved and I wrote an answer

Answer (score 2):

The location of Shrek's house used to be X: 76807 Z: 51209, but it has been moved to X: 78089 Z: 49919.

Source: [LOTR Minecraft Mod Wiki](http://lotrminecraftmod.wikia.com/wiki/Shrek's_House)